# Matlab: How to sum up values in a certain range depending on entries in other columns

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, sum, cumulative-sum

I'm pretty new to Matlab and not able to solve the following problem:

I've got three column vectors, **"Day", "Name", "Values"** each 300x1 and I need to sum up **"Values"** (cumulative) in a certain range which depend not only on the vector **"Name"** but also the vector **"Day"**.

*More precisely*, I want to sum up the values in vector **"Values"** for each category (vector **"Name"**) but only for a certain range (vector **"Day"**), let's say I want to sum up all the **"Values"** starting on **"Day"** 2, the **"Result"**-vector should look like (shortened example):

```
| Day | Name | Values | Result |
|-----|------|--------|------------|
| 1   | A    | 2      | 0          |
| 1   | C    | 9      | 0          |
| 1   | B    | 7      | 0          |
| 2   | D    | 1      | 1          |
| 2   | B    | 1      | 1          |
| 2   | A    | 3      | 3          |
| 2   | D    | 4      | 5          |
| 3   | D    | 9      | 14         |
| 3   | B    | 1      | 2          |
| 3   | C    | 3      | 3          |
| 3   | A    | 1      | 4          |
| 4   | D    | 3      | 17         |
```

Later on I would like to change the range, e.g. starting to sum up after **"Day"** 2, **"Day"** 3 and so on which would need to be adjustet for the starting "Day".

For my sum range starting on **"Day"** 2 I've created the following code but it does not work at all:

```
Result = zeros(size(Values));
a=unique(Name);
for k=1:length(a)
    for i = 1:length(Name)
        if Day(i) > 1
            Result(ismember(Name,a(k)))=cumsum(Values(ismember(Name,a(k))));
        end
    end
end
```

Is there anybody able to help?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the function [ismember()](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) is what you require here.

Try using another array to store the cumulative sums of each unique `Name` along with the function [find()](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) like so:

```
startDay = 2
NameList = unique(Name);
CumulSum = zeros(1, length(NameList));  % Array to store cumulative sum
Result = zeros(1, length(Name));

% For each row in the tabe
for row = 1:length(Name)

  % Check condition on Day
  if (Day(row) >= startDay)

    % Compute the cumulative sum
    % and store it in CumulSum array
    indx = find(NameList == Name(row));
    CumulSum(indx) = CumulSum(indx) + Values(row);

    % Use the cumulative sum as result for the row
    Result(row) = CumulSum(indx);

  end
end
```

Also, beware when using `unique()` on character arrays. You might want to ensure if the elements of `Name` are single characters.

Comment: `unique` actually works on `string`s (indicated with `""`) but you are right for chars/char-arrays (indicated by `''`). [Strings](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) have been introduces in R2016b and it still confuses me that they are not char-arrays in MATLAB;)